# How to install packages through pip?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a python gui automator and am supposed to do so through pip. Typing `pip install pyautogui` in the command prompt (as administrator) gives me many exceptions. Here is the printout:

```
pip install pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module '_socket'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Nate4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\nate4\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to the directory where your python is installed. (In my case it's C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32)
2) Find the directory called "Scripts"
3) Hold down SHIFT and right-click [image] on that folder. Then click "Open command window here"
4) A command prompt window will pop up. Type `pip install <packagename>` and press ENTER.

This method works for me when I install packages for my python through pip. Hope it helps you.